# How to write every two pages with TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to generate a pdf that will be double-sided printed. There are two different background images, depending on whether the page is front or back. The text must be written only on odd pages (front).
On the even pages (back), there must only be images. Then, if the text from page 1 overflows, it must be continued on page 3. How can I do that with TCPDF?

My code so far  (recto is for front, verso is for back):

```
$pdf->startPage();
$pdf->Image($img_file_recto, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 106); // (boolean) Boolean indicating if mode should be on or off , (float) Distance from the bottom of the page.
$pdf->writeHeaderRecto();
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 130, 8, 74, $bloc_body, 0, 0, false, true, '', true); // bloc body de la page
$pdf->writeFooterRecto();
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->setPage(2);
$pdf->Image($img_file_verso, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->endPage();
$pdf->startPage();
$pdf->Image($img_file_recto, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->Image($img_file_verso, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
$pdf->endPage();
$pdf->output($fileName, 'I');
```

This code generates a clean front page (background image+header+first part of text+footer), exactly what I want. 
However, the second page displays a reduced-size image on the left high corner directly followed by the rest of the text. 
Then the third page displays the reduced-size image on the left high corner and the header, but not the footer. Finally, the fourth page displays the reduced-size image on the left high corner and the footer.

Can anyone explain this weird behavior? NB : when setAutoPageBreak() is set to false, the images display properly, but the text overflows on the footer (106 from the bottom of the page).

Thank you for any help or redirection to a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a background image onto every page is straight out of [example 51](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_051/) in the documentation. We can add something similar to `$img_file = $this->page % 2 ? 'recto.jpg' : 'verso.jpg';` to put a different background on odd and even pages.

Then it's just a case of adding a new page every time an even page is created. I've done this by extending `endPage()` which works a bit better with the final page than extending `startPage()`.

You'll want to set some margins so that the text starts in the right place if it overruns the initial page.

```
class MyPDF extends TCPDF
{

    public function Header()
    {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // set background image
        $img_file = $this->page % 2 ? 'recto.jpg' : 'verso.jpg';
        $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }

    public function endPage($tocpage = false)
    {
        parent::endPage($tocpage);
        if ($this->page % 2) {
            $this->startPage();
            $this->endPage();
        }
    }

}

$bloc_body = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna felis sollicitudin mauris. Integer in mauris eu nibh euismod gravida. Duis ac tellus et risus vulputate vehicula. Donec lobortis risus a elit. Etiam tempor. Ut ullamcorper, ligula eu tempor congue, eros est euismod turpis, id tincidunt sapien risus a quam. Maecenas fermentum consequat mi. Donec fermentum. Pellentesque malesuada nulla a mi. Duis sapien sem, aliquet nec, commodo eget, consequat quis, neque. Aliquam faucibus, elit ut dictum aliquet, felis nisl adipiscing sapien, sed malesuada diam lacus eget erat. Cras mollis scelerisque nunc. Nullam arcu. Aliquam consequat. Curabitur augue lorem, dapibus quis, laoreet et, pretium ac, nisi. Aenean magna nisl, mollis quis, molestie eu, feugiat in, orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>';
$bloc_body .= $bloc_body;

$pdf = new MyPDF();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 106); // (boolean) Boolean indicating if mode should be on or off , (float) Distance from the bottom of the page.
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 130, 8, 74, $bloc_body, 0, 0, false, true, '', true); // bloc body de la page
$pdf->output($fileName, 'I');
```